# NodeJS express/request: piping a POST request with body parsing issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to pipe a request handling by a remote server, along with the following line:

Unfortunately pipe doesn't work well with post body, could you suggest how can I solve this issue?

```js
self.downloadPriceLists = function (req, res, next) {
  const options = {
    url: `http://${env.MAILER_HOST}:${env.MAILER_PORT}/getpricelist/`,
    method: 'POST',
    json: true,   // <--Very important!!!
    headers: req.headers,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
    body: {
      userID: req.user.id,
      exportAsOf: req.body.exportAsOf,
      activationDate: req.body.activationDate,
     },
  };
  console.log("options:", options);
  // remoteResponse :: res
  // remoteBody :: body
  const myReq = request.post(options, function (error, remoteResponse, remoteBody) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Disposition');
    remoteResponse.headers.hasOwnProperty('content-disposition') && res.setHeader('Content-disposition', remoteResponse.headers['content-disposition']);
    remoteResponse.headers.hasOwnProperty('content-type') && res.setHeader('Content-type', remoteResponse.headers['content-type']);
    if (error) {
      console.error('request fail:', error);
      return res.status(500).end('Error');
    }

    console.log('submit successful:', remoteResponse.headers);
    res.pipe(remoteBody);
  });


  // Handle errors
  myReq.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log("++++++++++++sendReq Handle errors:", err);
    res.status(500).end("Error:" + err);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Should you not be piping streams and not scalar data?
`res.pipe(remoteBody);` does look right to me, if anything, `res.pipe(remoteResponse);` seems more right.

Have you considered just writing the response of the inner request to the outer one without piping? Like so `res.json(remoteBody);` ?

Comment: Basically  with res.json(remoteBody); and res.send(remoteBody) it works tho, the file that  is received on front end side, comes corrupted and cannot be opened. Even if the original url sends a normal file. Normally with get requests the pipe solves this issue.